# How to enter a constant field in bitfield struct

Tags: c, struct, unions, bit-fields

Here is an example of a struct:

```
typedef struct {
   int8 SSPM:4;
   int8 CKP:1; 
   int8 SSPEN:1; 
   int8 SSPOV:1;
   int8 WCOL:1; 
} sspcon_layout;
```

(1) How do I create a constant value of arbitrary bit length in this struct e.g how to have two high bits between CKP and SSPEN?

(2) If the struct is not aligned to byte boundary, how do I find out how the final struct shall be like? e.g if I have a 9 bit long struct with the last field being 1 bit long, will it go into the MSB of the second byte or LSB?

(3) Also, what if the last field is 4 bits long and split between the first and second bytes? Will the 2 MSB of this 4 bit field be contiguos with the first 2 bits under all compilers or will they be split apart?

I am using the CCS PIC C Compiler.

Comment: Due to lack of defined layout, endianess, etc. it is in general a bad idea to use a bitmap struct. On the PIC16 it is even worse, as it might massively bloat the code. Use a normal **unsigned** integer and bitops. Using a signed integer for single bits is a bad idea in general, as that can only store the sign. For 2s complement this means you can only store `0` and **`-1`**.

Comment: when using `int8`, one bit of each field is the 'sign' bit.  Probably not what you want.  Suggest each field be `uint8_t`

Comment: @user3629249, you're quite right that a signed type is almost surely unwanted here, but how do you know that non-standard type `int8` is a signed type?

Comment: @JohnBollinger,  the `int8` signed/unsigned status will depend on what the OP defined it to be.  Your question would not be a consideration if the OP had used a definition from the header file: `stdint.h`.   So, *I* do not know, so I have to work with common usage of `int`

Comment: I am only using the CCS PIC C compiler, and none other

Answer (score 1):

the order of the bit fields in the enclosing struct is not defined in the standard and strictly depends on the underlying architecture.

I.E. big/little Endian and where bit 0 is defined (MSB or LSB)

this makes a struct of bit fields non portable.

If the sum of the fields is greater than the size of (the size of the field type used then the struct will cross to the next sizeof( ) bytes in memory.

This means,

if using uint8_t then each struct will be some multiple of 1.

if using unsigned int then each struct will be some multiple of sizeof(int) bytes.

This means, if using `unsigned int` for the field types and `sizeof(int)` is 4, then the struct could hold 32 bits.

It is also not defined which end of the struct will contain the undefined bit fields if say the struct is 32 bits long and only 25 bits defined.

Comment: This is correct in general thrust and some of the particulars, that the layout of bitfields within structs is largely implementation-dependent.  On the other hand, the assertion that the declared type of a bitfield has any relationship with size of the "addressible storage unit" wherein the bits are held is not backed by the standard.  Moreover, the assertions about the overall size of a struct are wholly unsupported (except that the size of *every* type is trivially a multiple of 1 byte), especially to the extent that they seem to imply, falsely, that the amount of padding must be minimized.

Comment: @JohnBollinger,  The struct size being a function of the individual field type/size is a detail that I acquired by writing a short program that (over various versions) printed out the size of the struct.  The program printed out `1` for field types of `char` and `uint8_t`  and printed out `4` for `unsigned int`.   I'm running ubuntu linux 14.04.4 and compiling/linking  with `gcc` version GNU C version 4.8.4 (x86_64-linux-gnu), GMP version 5.1.3, MPFR version 3.1.2-p3, and MPC version 1.0.1.  I have seen this kind of sizing with other OSs, other compilers.

Comment: Observing the behavior of one implementation does not provide much insight into the range of behaviors that are, in fact, allowed or required.  If you want to make an answer based on a particular implementation, then the most appropriate implementation for it is the one named by the OP: the CCS PIC C Compiler.  In any case, it is incumbent upon you to discriminate between comments intended to convey rules and freedoms derived from the C standard, and comments describing the behavior of a given implementation.

Comment: @JohnBollinger,  I have observed this behaviour on several different architectures and compiler combinations.  I gave my current implementation info, incase the question came up.  I clearly stated that the usage of bit fields in a struct was not portable.  And regarding your suggestion to report on the same architecture/compiler as the OP.  would require my having that compiler and architecture on hand, which I do not have available.   Were I the OP, I would just write a simple C program to try it out on the specific architecture.

Answer (score 0):

> (1) How do I create a constant value of arbitrary bit length in this struct e.g how to have two high bits between CKP and SSPEN?

You do not do so.  All other considerations aside, structure definitions such as the one you present describe only the types and sequence of the structure members, not their values.  You could declare a `const` bit field in the struct, but its value in any given instance of that structure would depend on the corresponding initializer (or lack of initializer).

Moreover, implementations have a significant amount of latitude in choosing the details of structure layout.  Here are some of the provisions specific to bitfields:

> An implementation may allocate any addressable storage unit large enough to hold a bit- field. If enough space remains, a bit-field that immediately follows another bit-field in a structure shall be packed into adjacent bits of the same unit. If insufficient space remains, whether a bit-field that does not fit is put into the next unit or overlaps adjacent units is implementation-defined. The order of allocation of bit-fields within a unit (high-order to low-order or low-order to high-order) is implementation-defined. The alignment of the addressable storage unit is unspecified.

(C2011 6.7.2.1/11)

> (2) If the struct is not aligned to byte boundary, how do I find out how the final struct shall be like? e.g if I have a 9 bit long struct with the last field being 1 bit long, will it go into the MSB of the second byte or LSB?

You can have a 9-bit long `struct` only if `CHAR_BIT` has the value `9`, since every type's representation has a size in bits that is a multiple of `CHAR_BIT`, and `CHAR_BIT` cannot have a value smaller than 8.  I don't know any implementation that uses `CHAR_BIT` different from 8.  You may have a structure in which only 9 bits are used to represent the members' values, but almost surely there would be padding either between the members or at the end, or both.  Details are at the discretion of the implementation, as is the overall size.

I would not be too surprised to see the overall size being 32 bits, 64, or even as many as 128 in various implementations, as some implementations apply a 4-byte or larger alignment (and therefore size) requirement to all structure types.  On the other hand, you might see as few as 16 bits, and you might be able to influence these details by implementation-specific means such as `#pragma`s and compilation options.

Since many aspects of the layout of structures is implementation-dependent, if you really want to predict how a structure will be laid out then your best recourse is to consult the documentation of the C implementation you are targeting.  Relying on such details is of course non-portable, and the details may or may not be documented in the first place.  As a last recourse, you can examine the layouts produced in practice to figure out how your implementation is doing it, but this has more diagnostic value than predictive value.

> (3) Also, what if the last field is 4 bits long and split between the first and second bytes? Will the 2 MSB of this 4 bit field be contiguos with the first 2 bits under all compilers or will they be split apart?

The standard does not specify, and it provides no reason for any confidence that different compilers will behave consistently in this regard.  Indeed, I'm uncertain how you could be confident that a given bitfield not exceeding 8 bits in width will, in fact, be split across two bytes in the structure representation.

Overall, although it's unclear what you're trying to do here, I am inclined to think that your approach to the problem is unsuitable.  To the extent that you seem to have some interest in consistency across compilers, I have pretty high confidence in that assessment.  If you need to manage details of a bit array, then do it *as* a bit array (as hosted inside an integer, byte array, or other
type).  You may find it convenient in that regard to define functions or macros for manipulating the parts.